# How do I add a target to a test scheme?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ocunit

I have configured unit testing for a project, and I need to use the classes that are in the run scheme also in the test scheme.

This because if I try to use a class that I use in the run scheme, I get a linker error, the linker does not recognize that (user defined) class.

I called the test bundle "TestBundle", I am able to test the application unless I use other classes. This is what I see when I try to edit the test scheme:

[image: Edit scheme screen]

It seems like there isn't a place for adding another target, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schemes RUN targets... they don't manage what a target is made up of.
they could also be called 'environments' or 'execution setups' or so :)

targets are managed under your project (when you click onto the blue project icon in the project navigator)

[image]

*note: I think that apple brought us schemes only to haze us ;D*

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. I added all the compile resources.